# Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null while printint content in a hidden div using ngxPrint

Tags: angular, hidden, getelementsbytagname

- My html

```html
  <div *ngIf="isShown" id="print-section"> 
      <!--Your html stuff that you want to print-->
         
  </div>
        
  <button printTitle="MyTitle"  printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>
```

- My .ts

```js
ngOnInit() { 
  this.isShown = false;
}
```

Why can't the div content be printed if I set `isShown` to false.

Answer (score 1):

The `*ngIf` is a syntactic sugar for the directive `[ngIf]`. So your template would actually be expanded to

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="isShown">
  <div id="print-section"> 
    <!--Your html stuff that you want to print-->
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The `ng-template` is Angular specific implementation of more generic HTML `template` tag. So as you see when the condition is false, the `div` isn't hidden like you say but rather not rendered yet. So when you attempt `getElementsByTagName`, the element isn't available yet.

As a workaround, you could use CSS to hide the element instead of `*ngIf`. Try the following

```html
<div [style.display]="isShown ? 'block' : 'none'" id="print-section"> 
  <!--Your html stuff that you want to print-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `[hidden]="true"` instead of `*ngIf="isShown"` and it will work.**

app.component.html -

```
<div [hidden]="true" id="print-section"> 
  <h1>HELLO WORLD!!!</h1>
</div>
<button printTitle="MyTitle"  printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>
```

app.component.ts -

```
export class AppComponent { }
```

app.module.ts -

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxPrintModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.json -

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.3",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
```

Output -

[image: ngx-print PDF]

Comment: Getting same 'getElementsByTagName' error from below code mentioned by @Michael D -

`<ng-template [ngIf]="isShown">`
  `<div id="print-section"> `
    `<h1>HELLO WORLD!!!</h1>`
  `</div>`
`</ng-template>`
`<button printTitle="MyTitle"  printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>`

Comment: What do you mean getting same error? I said the `*ngIf` will expand internally to this version and that is the actual reason for the error. My solution is to use `[style.display]` similar to the `[hidden]` as shown in your answer.